Descope Redirect Uri error in production for expo app
I followed the tutorial on https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#descope. It says that i can use the below for redirectURI
const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri();

However, it does work when I run the app using npx expo start
However, when I submit to app store, it just says
{"errorCode":"E011003","errorDescription":"Request is invalid","errorMessage":"The redirect_uri field must have a hostname","message":"The redirect_uri field must have a hostname"}

Below is my code
const descopeProjectId = "xxxxxx";
const descopeUrl = `https://api.descope.com/${descopeProjectId}`;
const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri();

export default function SignupOrLogin() {
    const [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = React.useState(null);
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState(null);
    const discovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery(descopeUrl);
    const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState<UserProfile>({} as UserProfile)

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
        {
            clientId: descopeProjectId,
            responseType: AuthSession.ResponseType.Code,
            redirectUri,
            usePKCE: true,
            scopes: ["openid", "profile", "email"],
        },
        discovery
    );

I have attempted to search online for something else, but I'm not quite sure what to substitude for redirectUri.

I fixed that by putting parameter to the makeRedirectUri
const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
  native: "com.<accountName>.<projectNameOrID>://redirect",
});

